# How can I add image within list record ?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

How can I add image within list record?

My list record contains both string and image.
I have one object containing a string and an image. I need to add that object string and image into a list.

The string and the image must be within same list raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a start in rendering images into lists, you could use this [tutorial](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/09/18/displaying-images-in-a-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/):